# SharePoint 2007 - Remind user of check-out documents

Tags: document-library, document, check-out, check-in

May I know if it is possible to remind user who have check-out a document for a period of time, to check in their document? (I notice that sometime user do forget to check-in their documents, so was wondering if SharePoint can help to remind user to check-in. )

The reminder can appear for every X minutes if the document is still check-out. (where X can be 15 minutes, 30 minutes or etc)

Comment: How are you wanting to notify the user?

Comment: The reminder can be a email sent to the user ~or~ a pop-up message from SharePoint ~or~ a pop-up message that is display in the document itself ~or~ etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Console Application in Visual Studio that queries the document libraries for items where the Checked Out To column is not NULL.  Then email the users in question with the list of documents they still have checked out.

You could then have the Console Application set to run on the SharePoint Server (as a Windows Scheduled Task) every 15, 30, or 60 minutes, etc.

Comment: Hi John, so does it mean that I need the Visual Studio to be installed on the SharePoint 2007 server in order to create the console application? (I remember that any coding from Visual Studio that interact with SharePoint libraries or lists need to have the Visual Studio install on the SharePoint itself - do correct me if I remember wrongly.)

Comment: To interact with the object model directly, yes. Or remotely you could use SharePoints Lists.asbx web service.

Comment: Lists.asmx that is.

Comment: Hi John, do you have sample code & instruction on how to use the SharePoint Lists.asmx web service from a Console Application in Visual Studio 2008 & send out email to perform the reminder scheduler?

Comment: Here is the info on the web service - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Here is the info on sending email from .net http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this out May be it is useful to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPScheduedReminders.aspx

Comment: Please write a line or two about the solution and *then* link to the post